# regex : match telephone number with or without non-numerical character

Tags: regex

Someone is spamming my site with fake telephone numbers, I want to filter all telephone numbers on my site.
The numbers are in format :

```
0862123652
```

So ten numbers where the first one is always 0, but spammers also use :

```
08 62 1 2   3 ///6 \\\52
08 62 1 .....2 ***  3+++ ///6 \\\52
```

So I cannot filter these ones with parttern like `0[0-9]{9}`. How could I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with `0[0-9]{9}`?

Comment: If you use `0[0-9]{9}`, wouldn't the above examples be filtered since they contain non-digit characters?

Comment: I didn't quite get the ones used by spammers. Mind elaborating?

Comment: @Pranav C Balan This pattern does not work for non digit characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the string has *exactly* 10 digits (starting with `0`):

```
^\D*0\D*(?:\d\D*){9}$
```

If you need to narrow it down, you could change every `\D` with the specific set of symbols that may occur between digits. For example:

```
^[.*+/\\ ]*0[.*+/\\ ]*(?:\d[.*+/\\ ]*){9}$
```

---

I'm positive you could create these kind of expressions if you read a couple of minutes about regex syntax, so allow me to recommend:

1. [Regular Expressions Tutorial (regular-expressions.info)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). A quite comprehensive tutorial to learn regex.
2. [regex101.com](https://regex101.com). Allows you to test different expressions and understand the way a pattern matches the subjet string.